# add Symfony Assert in a Callback

Tags: validation, symfony, callback, assert

I, i have to add an Assert to an atribute when other atribute is equal than something. Like this:

```
/**
* @Assert\Callback(methods={"isChildMinor",)
*/
class PatientData
{
/**
 * @Assert\Date()
 */
public $birthday;

public $role;

public function isChildMinor(ExecutionContext $context)
{
    if ($this->role == 3 && check @assert\isMinor() to $birtday) {
    =>add violation
    }
}
```

so, i want check if the patient is minor (with assert or somethings else) if the role is equal than 3. How do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do, what you want.

1) You could make it right in the form. Like that:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
  $yourEntity = $builder->getData();
  //here you start the field, you want to validate
  $fieldOptions = [
     'label'     => 'Field Name',
      'required' => true,
  ];
  if ($yourEntity->getYourProperty != 'bla-bla-bla') {
    $fieldOptions[] = 'constraints' => [
       new Assert\NotBlank([
          'message' => 'This is unforgivable! Fill the field with "bla-bla-bla" right now!',
       ]),
    ],
  }
  $builder->add('myField', TextType::class, $fieldOptions);
```

2) Other way - is to make your custom validation callback in your Entity and play with direct asserts there. It's possible, I think.

3) But the optimal way, from my point of view - is to use several asserts with validation groups. You need to specify Assert\isMinor(groups={"myCustomGroup"}) on birthday field. And then, in your form:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
  $resolver->setDefaults([
     'validation_groups' => function (FormInterface $form) {
        $yourEntity = $form->getData();
        if ($yourEntity->role !== 3) {
            return ['Default', 'myCustomGroup'];
        }
        return ['Default'];
     },
```

Hope this'll be helpful for you.

Comment: Hi, i'm trying to implement this, I have one problem: the things that i don't understand is how you obtain the validation to return as 'myCustomGruop'. I specify the assert Minor like this:

/**
     * @Assert\Date()
     * @Assert\GreaterThan("-18 years")
     */
    public $birthday;

so i don't know how put in that return array.

Comment: i understand with this http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/options_resolver.html and the group validation and now all works fine. Thanks for the help